# PHPBB Optimal YouTube BBCode

Tags: html, youtube, phpbb, bbcode

Anyone knows the optimal bbcode to embed youtube videos in PHPBB3? I use the follwing:

BBCode Usage:

```
[youtube]http://{SIMPLETEXT1}youtube.com/watch?v={SIMPLETEXT2}[/youtube]
```

HTML Replacement:

```
<object width="560" height="315">
    <param name="movie" value="http://{SIMPLETEXT1}youtube.com/v/{SIMPLETEXT2}"></param>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
    <embed src="http://{SIMPLETEXT1}youtube.com/v/{SIMPLETEXT2}" 
           type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
           width="560" 
           height="315" 
           allowscriptaccess="always" 
           allowfullscreen="true">
    </embed>
</object>
```

This seems to have some issues and doesn't translate to HTML when the URL the user puts is something like `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vS6VBOeJ-i4&feature=related`.

I would like to make an HTML Replacement so it can replace the user's link into the new embed style of YouTube with the iFrame, but independent of URL attributes while also using the `wmode=transparent`, since I also use Shadowbox.

Answer (score 6):

While riot_starter's solution works, it does not seem to work with https URLs which YouTube forces nowdays. So here is a workaround that should work in all scenarios:

BBCode:

```
[youtube]http{TEXT4}://{TEXT1}youtube.com/{TEXT2}v={IDENTIFIER}{TEXT3}[/youtube]
```

HTML:

```
<object width="425" height="350">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/{IDENTIFIER}&hl=en_US&fs=1&"></param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/{IDENTIFIER}&hl=en_US&fs=1&" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="425" height="350"></embed>
</object>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the best version I have found so far. Works with www.youtube.com, youtube.com, regional subdomains (nl.youtube.com), and with any youtube url parameters (for example including &feature=...).

BBCode usage:

`[youtube]http://{TEXT1}youtube.com/{TEXT2}v={IDENTIFIER}{TEXT3}[/youtube]`

HTML replacement:

```
<object width="425" height="350">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/{IDENTIFIER}&hl=en_US&fs=1&"></param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/{IDENTIFIER}&hl=en_US&fs=1&" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="425" height="350"></embed>
</object>
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this

BBCode Usage `[youtube]{IDENTIFIER}[/youtube]`

HTML Replacement

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/{IDENTIFIER}" width="425" height="350">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/{IDENTIFIER}" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
</object>
```

Now a user can just do `[youtube]oHg5SJYRHA0[/youtube]` to get the video embedded into the post.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the  on the embed code not

works ALOT better!!!
tested on 3.0.11

example:  http://fwkzt.site.nfoservers.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=17&p=33&sid=2d89389670c660b3a345fd59bac5c4ff#p33

code used:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/{YOUTUBE}?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: OK but what about the youtu.be links from the sharing tool?